# confused about adding apps to INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: django

I just started learning Django and I watch 2 different courses on Youtube. And adding apps to a project got me confused right from the start. In the first tutorial they tell me to add an app to a list of installed apps like  this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
     ...
     ...
     ...
]
```

and in the other tutorial they simply add the app name to the list:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog',
     ...
     ...
     ...
]
```

Could you please explain me the difference? And how should I add apps to the project?

Comment: Stick to the shortest if it works. Perhaps there is a more explicit way to do it in case you have two apps using the name `blog`

Answer (score 3):

You add the app’s configuration class (subclassed from [AppConfig](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig)) if you want to configure certain properties of the app (e.g. the label it's identified by in the Admin interface).

The documentation has an [Application configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/applications/#s-application-configuration) section that deals with that.